# Scatter Plot and Regression Line

Tags: regression, discrete-data, scatterplot

using the dataset CO2 as an example. After I find the regression lines of uptake and Plant (a factor with 12 levels)

```
lm(uptake ~ Plant, data = CO2) 

Call:
lm(formula = uptake ~ Plant, data = CO2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      Plant.L      Plant.Q  
   27.21310    -22.94230     -4.61669  
    Plant.C      Plant^4      Plant^5  
    4.66802      2.33920      4.31450  
    Plant^6      Plant^7      Plant^8  
   -0.03902     -2.03649     -3.27825  
    Plant^9     Plant^10     Plant^11  
   -9.06702      0.54631      1.91215
```

Is there a way I can plot this and add the regression lines to the plot? Plant is a discrete variable, so what should the graph's x axis be? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us what you might mean by "regression lines"?  That phrase doesn't seem to make any sense for this model.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply plot this using

```
plot()
```

However, I do have to agree with the other comments that you should question whether this makes any sense whatsoever.